# Why can we consider this subsequence in $L^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I am trying to understand a step in the following proof of completeness of $L^p$ in [Stein-Shakarchi's Functional Analysis](http://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9627.pdf). (See the proof on page 5 of the link or at the end of this post.)

At the beginning of the proof, it is said that

> Let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a Cauchy sequence in $L^p$, and consider a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ of $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ with the following property $\|f_{n_{k+1}}-f_{n_k}\|\le 2^{-k}$ for all $k\geq 1$.

**Question:** Why can the sequence be considered as it is?

On a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/BWnV8fBlDQQ?t=870), it explains about a similar subsequence.

I still don't understand why for  $n,m>n_k$ $\Vert f_{n}-f_{m}\Vert_p\implies \Vert f_{n_k}-f_{n_{k+1}}\Vert_p$, thus an increasing subsequence. Why is it justified to make $n$ to depend on $k$, $n_k$?

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What happened to all the $\sum$s?

Comment: I don't know, I don't know why the author omitted them all;

Comment: Basically the trick here is to replace the Cauchy sequence by a subsequence that converges **really quickly**.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown What kind of convergence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authors mention at the beginning of the proof that

> The argument is essentially the same as for $L^1$ (or $L^2$); see Section 2, Chapter 2 and Section 1, Chapter 4 in [Book III](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/8008.html).

It is said clearly there (see also a snapshot at the end) that

> The existence of such subsequence is guaranteed by the fact that $\|f_{n}-f_{m}\|\leq \epsilon$ whenever $n,m\geq N(\epsilon)$, so that it suffices to take $n_k=N(2^{-k})$.

[Added for elaboration.]

There exists an integer $N(2^{-1})>0$ such that **for all** $n,m\geq N(2^{-1})$,
$$
\|f_{n}-f_{m}\|\leq 2^{-1}\tag{1}.
$$
There exists an integer $N(2^{-2})>N(2^{-1})$ such that **for all** $n,m\geq N(2^{-2})$,
$$
\|f_{n}-f_{m}\|\leq 2^{-2}\tag{2}.
$$
There exists an integer $N(2^{-3})>N(2^{-2})$ such that **for all** $n,m\geq N(2^{-3})$,
$$
\|f_{n}-f_{m}\|\leq 2^{-3}\tag{2}.
$$
... so on and so forth.

Now, let $n_1=N(2^{-1})$, $n_2=N(2^{-2})$, $n_3=N(2^{-3})$, $\cdots$.

Since $n_1,n_2\geq N(2^{-1})$, we have by (1)
$$
\|f_{n_2}-f_{n_1}\|\leq 2^{-1}.
$$

Since $n_2,n_3\geq N(2^{-2})$, we have by (2)
$$
\|f_{n_3}-f_{n_2}\|\leq 2^{-2}.
$$

Since $n_3,n_4\geq N(2^{-3})$, we have by (3)
$$
\|f_{n_4}-f_{n_3}\|\leq 2^{-3}.
$$

... so on and so forth.

---

The following is a snapshot of the beginning of the proof for completeness of $L^1$ in Stein-Shakarchi's Book III (page 70 Theorem 2.2).

> [image]

Comment: Why can we take the sequence as an increasing sequence?

Comment: What do you mean by "increasing sequence"? Are you asking why $n_1<n_2<n_3<\cdots$?

Comment: See my edit. Not that $\{f_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is NOT necessarily an increasing sequence. In fact one may talk about a sequence of complex-valued functions and thus no such thing as "increasing sequence" here. One can say that the subscripts $\{n_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ form an increasing sequence though.

Comment: Got it Jack thanks. Do we take this W.L.O.G $N(2^{-2})>N(2^{-1})$? Because $2^{-2}<2^{-1}$ actually

Comment: Well, I would not use "WLOG" there. Since $2^{-2}<2^{-1}$, we are taking a *smaller* $\epsilon$. On the other hand, we want to pick *one* positive integer $N(2^{-2})$ such that (i) $N(2^{-2})>N(2^{-1})$ (ii) for all $n,m\geq N(2^{-2})$, the inequality (2) holds. There are of course lots of other choices of $N(2^{-2})$ that would work, but we only need *one* such $N(2^{-2})$.

Answer (score 3):

If $\{f_n\}_n$ is Cauchy, for each $k\in\Bbb N$ we can find an $N_k$ (depending on the $k$ we just chose) such that

$$ \|f_n - f_m\| < 2^{-k} \quad\text{ whenever } n,m\geq N_k.$$

For $k+1$, we likewise get

$$ \|f_n - f_m\| < 2^{-k-1} \quad\text{ whenever } n,m\geq N_{k+1}.$$

Now, both inequalities will hold for $n,m \geq \max\{N_k,N_{k+1}\}$, so we can choose $N_{k+1} > N_k$, and similarly we can choose an $N_{k+2} > N_{k+1} > N_{k}$ for $2^{-k-2}$ so that

$$\|f_{N_k} - f_{N_{k+1}}\| < 2^{-k}\quad\text{and}\quad \|f_{N_{k+1}} - f_{N_{k+2}}\| < 2^{-k-1}$$

by choosing $n = N_k$ and $m = N_{k+1}$, etc in the first inequalities above.

Comment: Thank you. Does the subsequence $f_{N_k}$ converge pointwise?

Comment: You're welcome :) And no, $L^p$ convergence does not imply pointwise convergence in general.

Comment: it does not hold in general then there exist the  possibility of $f_{N_k}$ to converge pointwise?

Comment: Yes, if you take all the functions to be equal, for example. Or, for continuous functions in $L^1([0,1])$, uniform convergence implies both pointwise and $L^1$ convergence, so both can occur simultaneously.

Comment: On this $\|f_{N_k} - f_{N_{k+1}}\| < 2^{-k}\quad\text{and}\quad \|f_{N_{k+1}} - f_{N_{k+2}}\| < 2^{-k-1}$ what is the _whenever_ condition?

Comment: No whenever condition, at this point I was selecting a specific sequence $(N_k)_{k\geq 1}$.

Comment: I don't get it. Also should not be $\|f_{N_k} - f_{N_{k+1}}\| < 2^{-k-2}\quad\text{and}\quad \|f_{N_{k+1}} - f_{N_{k+2}}\| < 2^{-k-3}$ ? Following the analogy of the first inequalities above in your answer